# Docker Compose healthcheck: service never becomes unhealthy

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-healthcheck

I have a compose file with three services (database, backend and frontend). Backend depends on database being healthy, and frontend depends on backend being healthy.

Database (postgres) checks for its own health using `pg_isready` and backend (FastAPI) checks for its health via an endpoint `http://localhost:8080/healthcheck`

Compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  
  database:
    image: postgres:14-alpine
    healthcheck:
      test: pg_isready -U postgres
      interval: 1s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 10s

  backend:
    depends_on:
      database:
        condition: service_healthy

    image: backend-api-image
    build: 
      context: backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile

    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - './backend:/backend'

    healthcheck:
      test: wget --no-verbose --tries=1 --spider http://localhost:8080/healthcheck || exit 1
      interval: 1s
      timeout: 5s

  frontend:
    image: my-frontend
    depends_on:
      backend:
        condition: service_healthy
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

FastAPI app

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

app = FastAPI()

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

@app.get('/healthcheck')
def get_healthcheck():
    return 'OK'
```

**So far this all works as expected**. If, for example I were to have a typo in my `healthcheck` endpoint route (in my app), startup would fail, like so:

```
database  | 2023-06-01 23:01:44.410 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
database  | 2023-06-01 23:01:44.410 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
database  | 2023-06-01 23:01:44.411 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
database  | 2023-06-01 23:01:44.414 UTC [22] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-06-01 22:51:10 UTC
database  | 2023-06-01 23:01:44.417 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
backend   | INFO:     Will watch for changes in these directories: ['/backend']
backend   | INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8080 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
backend   | INFO:     Started reloader process [1] using StatReload
backend   | INFO:     Started server process [8]
backend   | INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
backend   | INFO:     Application startup complete.
backend   | INFO:     127.0.0.1:41294 - "GET /healthcheck HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found
backend   | INFO:     127.0.0.1:41296 - "GET /healthcheck HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found
backend   | INFO:     127.0.0.1:41298 - "GET /healthcheck HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found
dependency failed to start: container backend is unhealthy
```

Where I'm getting confused is, that after a successful startup, if I change the app in such a way to make `backend` become unhealthy, the container would detect the change and the check would return a `404` (as expected) but it would never become unhealthy.

```
database  | 2023-06-01 23:06:37.396 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
database  | 2023-06-01 23:06:37.396 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
database  | 2023-06-01 23:06:37.397 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
database  | 2023-06-01 23:06:37.400 UTC [22] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-06-01 23:06:34 UTC
database  | 2023-06-01 23:06:37.403 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
backend   | INFO:     Will watch for changes in these directories: ['/backend']
backend   | INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:8080 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
backend   | INFO:     Started reloader process [1] using StatReload
backend   | INFO:     Started server process [9]
backend   | INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
backend   | INFO:     Application startup complete.
backend   | INFO:     127.0.0.1:49450 - "GET /healthcheck HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
frontend  | 
frontend  | > frontend@0.0.0 dev
frontend  | > vite --host
frontend  | 
frontend  | Forced re-optimization of dependencies
frontend  | 
frontend  |   VITE v4.3.1  ready in 285 ms
frontend  | 
frontend  |   ➜  Local:   http://localhost:5173/
frontend  |   ➜  Network: http://172.26.0.4:5173/
backend   | INFO:     127.0.0.1:57966 - "GET /healthcheck HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
backend   | INFO:     127.0.0.1:57968 - "GET /healthcheck HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
backend   | INFO:     127.0.0.1:57982 - "GET /healthcheck HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
backend   | INFO:     127.0.0.1:57992 - "GET /healthcheck HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
backend   | INFO:     127.0.0.1:58002 - "GET /healthcheck HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
backend   | INFO:     127.0.0.1:58012 - "GET /healthcheck HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
backend   | INFO:     127.0.0.1:58018 - "GET /healthcheck HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
backend   | WARNING:  StatReload detected changes in 'src/main.py'. Reloading...
backend   | INFO:     Shutting down
backend   | INFO:     Waiting for application shutdown.
backend   | INFO:     Application shutdown complete.
backend   | INFO:     Finished server process [9]
backend   | INFO:     Started server process [76]
backend   | INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
backend   | INFO:     Application startup complete.
backend   | INFO:     127.0.0.1:58028 - "GET /healthcheck HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found
backend   | INFO:     127.0.0.1:58040 - "GET /healthcheck HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found
backend   | INFO:     127.0.0.1:35092 - "GET /healthcheck HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found
backend   | INFO:     127.0.0.1:35098 - "GET /healthcheck HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found
backend   | INFO:     127.0.0.1:35102 - "GET /healthcheck HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found
backend   | INFO:     127.0.0.1:35116 - "GET /healthcheck HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found
backend   | INFO:     127.0.0.1:35126 - "GET /healthcheck HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found
backend   | INFO:     127.0.0.1:35134 - "GET /healthcheck HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found
```

**What I expected:**

While running after a successful startup, upon changing the `backend` code in such a way that its healthcheck would fail, I expected `frontend` to exit or become degraded somehow, as its health dependency has failed.

**What happened:**

Everything kept running as if nothing happened, even though the `backend` healthcheck returned a failing value.

**My questions:**

- Is the healthcheck **only** valid during startup to wait for a container to be "ready"? [Documentation seems to suggest so](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/).
- If so, then why keep checking for health after successful startup?
- If not, why is the `backend` container not being marked as unhealthy when changes cause its healthcheck to fail while running?
- Is there a way to degrade a container to unhealthy while running after a successful startup?
- I'm aware that I can use `kill 1` instead of `exit 1` and that would cause `backend` container to stop, but doesn't seem very clean.

Comment: just a FYI depends_on is no longer supported in compose version 3.

Comment: @jmvcollaborator Can you elaborate on that? [There is an entry for it](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#depends_on) in the compose file v3 documentation and it even adds a note about "Controlling startup order", that links to [documentation about things like service_started and service_healthy](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In trying to reproduce the behavior you've described, the first problem I ran into is that the standard version of `wget` will make `HEAD` requests when using the `--spider` option, so that your healthcheck results in:

```
HEAD /healthcheck HTTP/1.1" 405 Method Not Allowed
```

This is using `wget` version `1.21` as installed in the `python:3.11` image. I modified the healthcheck to look like this (and dropped the irrelevant parts of your `docker-compose.yaml`):

```
version: '3'
services:

  backend:
    image: backend-api-image
    build:
      context: backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile

    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - './backend:/backend'

    healthcheck:
      test: wget --no-verbose -O /dev/null --tries=1 http://localhost:8080/healthcheck || exit 1
      interval: 1s
      timeout: 5s
```

I have your example FastAPI code in `backend/backend.py`, and my `backend/Dockerfile` looks like:

```
FROM python:3.11

WORKDIR /app
RUN python3 -m venv .venv
ENV PATH=/app/.venv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN . .venv/bin/activate && pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . ./

CMD ["uvicorn", "--reload", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8080", "backend:app"]
```

When I run `docker-compose up`, I see:

```
backend_1  | INFO:     127.0.0.1:44856 - "GET /healthcheck HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
backend_1  | INFO:     127.0.0.1:44884 - "GET /healthcheck HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
```

...and the container enters the "healthy" state:

```
NAME                  IMAGE               COMMAND                  SERVICE             CREATED             STATUS                    PORTS
webserver_backend_1   backend-api-image   "uvicorn --reload --…"   backend             24 seconds ago      Up 23 seconds (healthy)   0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, :::8080->8080/tcp
```

If I `docker exec` into the container and modify the FastAPI application to return an error, so that the code looks like this:

```
backend_1  | WARNING:  StatReload detected changes in 'backend.py'. Reloading...
backend_1  | INFO:     Shutting down
backend_1  | INFO:     Waiting for application shutdown.
backend_1  | INFO:     Application shutdown complete.
backend_1  | INFO:     Finished server process [8]
backend_1  | INFO:     Started server process [1050]
backend_1  | INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
backend_1  | INFO:     Application startup complete.
backend_1  | INFO:     127.0.0.1:44618 - "GET /healthcheck HTTP/1.1" 400 Bad Request
backend_1  | INFO:     127.0.0.1:48912 - "GET /healthcheck HTTP/1.1" 400 Bad Request
```

And the container enters the "unhealthy" state:

```
NAME                  IMAGE               COMMAND                  SERVICE             CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS
webserver_backend_1   backend-api-image   "uvicorn --reload --…"   backend             2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes (unhealthy)   0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, :::8080->8080/tcp
```

That all seems to work as expected: the container health status changes as the response from the FastAPI service changes.

Here are some questions to help further diagnose things on your end:

- What does the `Dockerfile` for your FastAPI service look like? In particular, what's the base image?
- Have you verified that the `wget` command in that image returns an error code as expected for a non-200 response from the server?

Comment: I'm using `python:3.10-alpine` as a source image for the `backend` container, which comes with BusyBox 1.35 - I believe `wget` included uses `GET` as its default verb. Upon closer inspection, the container IS becoming `unhealthy`, it seems like it's a misunderstanding on my part to believe that this sudden `unhealthy` state would stop the containers that depend on it, but they continue to run normally.